# How to set previous value when cancelling a drop-down list with Angular Directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that you add to any 'select' element to give it a cool modal pop up and add a custom message (which I omitted from this example).

I'm trying, in the directive, to make it so when the user clicks cancel the value goes back to what it was, otherwise it appears that it has changed. I can this normally in jquery without this weird modal setup I have

Here's a working plnkr with info - http://plnkr.co/edit/JRi5AsarX9AztCWLx1QR?p=preview

Angular Directive:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']).directive('ngConfirmClick', ['$modal',
    function($modal) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            ngConfirmClick:"&",
            item:"="
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            if(element.context.tagName == 'SELECT'){

                $("select").change(function() {

                        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                            $scope.ok = function() {
                                $modalInstance.close();
                            };
                            $scope.cancel = function() {
                                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                            };
                        };


                    var message = attrs.ngConfirmMessage || "Are you sure ?";

                    var modalHtml =  '<div class="modal-header" id="confirm-box"><h4 id="title-color" class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Please Confirm</h4></div><div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>';
                        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>';


                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        template: modalHtml,
                        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
                    });

                    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                        scope.ngConfirmClick({item:scope.item}); 
                    }, function() {
                    });
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
]);
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <b>This is the list I'm looping through:</b> <h3>{{peoples}}</h3>

         When I cancel I want to return to the value Sam or whatever value was selected at the time of cancel.

        <select ng-confirm-click="sendPost()" ng-model="selectedPerson" class="form-control-dropdown" ng-options="people as people for people in peoples"></select>

  </div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.selectedPerson = 'Sam';
  $scope.peoples = ['Sam', 'Randy', 'Joe'] ;  

  $scope.sendPost = function(){
    console.log('this makes a POST call normally');
  };


};
```

I have tried a lot to get this working, some methods more hacky than other. My problem is I for some reason can't figure out, once I'm inside the $modalinstance to pass the original value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iT0vVXhZ71fK9G4eRJ36?p=preview).

I did a small change. I have added ngModel in scope variable and just maintaining the oldValue in the variable from `scope.ngModel`

Comment: Thanks Shripal. One thing, if I have more than one 'select' on the page, it adds that many modal pop ups. For example I updated the plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/f17BF8CPFNBVbThha9aJ?p=preview  How could I only allow just 1 popup instead of having to hit cancel twice. Do I need to grab the index and then do it that way?

Comment: I have updated the plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/yF41X1teCn0HvoTZWtvd?p=preview. You just need to change the selector in your directive.

Comment: the element is unique? ah that makes sense. Very cool thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should really make the SELECT be part of the directive rather than using jQuery to add events. Bind the select to a property using ng-model. You can put a watch on that value to popup the modal when it changes. You can have 2 values, one the previous value, one the current. If the user hits the "Cancel" on the popup then just set the value back to the previous value. Something like this:

```
       myApp.directive(.....

         return {
           template: '<select ng-model="newValue">......',
           scope: {
            previousSelectedValue: '='    // Whatever you want selected by default
         },
          link: function(scope) {

            scope.newValue = previousSelectedValue;

            scope.watch('newValue',function(val) {

                // Popup modal. 
                // On Cancel reset newValue=previousSelectedValue 
                // On okay just leave it and set previousSelectedValue to newValue

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it using small shared factory. So that it can be handled globally.
Service is acting as communicator between the controllers and also used angular events.

Here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iEn9ACrrN5vFgUHdgXj?p=preview)

Below is the code of factory which maintains the data of selectedPerson.

```
app.factory('saveData', function() {
  this.data = {};
  var setSelected = function(newObj) {
    this.data = newObj;
  }
  var getSelected = function() {
    return this.data;
  }
  return {
    setSelected: setSelected,
    getSelected: getSelected
  };
});
```

Hope this will be helpful thanks.